# Move Cursor to next text Field when press Enter

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script file. I am call my div id="AppContainer " in this script when press enter.This code is working on only chrome browser but not working in other browser.What is the problem?

```
  HTML:
    <div id="AppContainer">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#AppContainer input').keydown(function(e){
         if(e.keyCode==13){       

            if($(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').attr('type')=='submit'){// check for submit button and submit form on enter press
             return true;
            }

            $(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').focus();

           return false;
         }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It works in all browsers. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hr0z5rjy/)

Comment: Try `if (e.which == 13) {` instead. jQuery standardizes different browsers key-code properties to `which`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#AppContainer').on('keydown', 'input:text', function (e) {
        if (13 === e.which) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).next('input:text').focus();
        }
    });
});
```