# Switch text field on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

No answers that I have found online have worked.

When my page loads, I have my JS file select the first textfield; which works.
I then want it so that if the enter key is pressed while in a textfield it then proceeds to the next textfield. Right now I have...

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

which doesn't work.

and my inputs are...

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

I apologize if I've done something dumb, but I've been trying to figure this out for far too long.

Comment: how can your password be input type text?

Comment: have you include jquery on page ?

Comment: It is working perfectly as you expected while running on jsfiddle, have you included jquery? is there any error in the console?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643284/move-cursor-to-next-text-field-when-press-enter

Comment: instead of `e.keycode` use `e.which`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to point your code snippet inside document ready function. Like below

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e) {
          var key_code = e.keyCode || e.which;
          if(key_code == 13)
          {
              $(this).nextAll('input[type="text"]').first().focus();
          }
     });
 });
```

To be conscious suggest to use `nextAll('input[type="text"]').first().focus()` if there have any other DOM before second text input field.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there's some script error. On Chrome, Press Ctrl + Shift + J.

Just add autofocus HTML attribute to the first input field.

Your password should be made input type password.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" autofocus />

<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine make sure there is any error thrown in your browser console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
   $(this).next().focus();
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is html

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" data-selected="true" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" data-selected="false" />
```

Here is JS

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('[data-selected=false]').focus();
    $('[data-selected=false]').attr('data-selected', true);
    $(this).attr('data-selected', false);
    }
});
```

Here is fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tm8yxL1m/

**Explanation:**

I have used data-selected="true" to check whether the field is selected. When user presses enter. I manipulate it to false and make other true

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />


$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
     $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` selector with jQuery below code will work for `input type="text"`, `input type="password"` also for `<select>` tags..

See online [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yad65hte/).
**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
<select style="width:100px">
<option>A</option>
<option>b</option>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" autocomplete="off" />
</select>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:first , select').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

1. First change your `e.keyCode` to `e.which`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
         $(this).next().focus();
      }
    }); 
});
```

2. Check whether you have jquery in your html or not.
3. It may be possible that  your html that you have provided is
   enclosed in a form with a submit button. If so then even if you have provided your `keyup` event, your form will submit. That's why you are not seeing the result.
4. password should be `type = password`. Just a advice
           outside your query.